# Angular Reactive Forms and Recursion

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I have a recursion

app-root.component.html

```
<div [formGroup]="form">
some content
<app-root></app-root>
</div>
```

How can I use same form group and form controls in my recursion? Something like :

```
<div [formGroup]="form">
some content
<app-root
[formGroup]="form"
></app-root>
</div>
```

Comment: Not sure if it is allowed to have form groups with same name. By the way, what do you want to achieve by this?

Comment: I don't need the same name:) I think we can do it with Input may be. I want to bind parent  form control's to recursion. I have required fields, And I have a save button, when required input field is empty in parent component, button is disabled, I want the same for my recursion. When my recursion's required field is empty, I need that save button become disabled in parent component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement ControlValueAccessor interface in app.component.ts and add NG_VALIDATORS as well.

Comment: can I get more details from U plz?

Comment: https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/03/14/custom-validators-in-angular-2.html

https://medium.com/@majdasab/implementing-control-value-accessor-in-angular-1b89f2f84ebf

Comment: this method works in custom form controls. here you are using app component as a form control when used recursively. so you need to implement custom validator for your whole app component so that it can be used by root app component to validate child app components.